# Sorting and ordering Vectors lists in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, vector

**Sorting Vector lists of X, Y, Z values in Python**

Hello, can someone please point me in the direction for a *slightly complex* sorting of a python list - (currently a list not a tuple)

I have a list of vectors that I wish to sort to plot in 3D space, the desired output is that they are indexed like a book, reading from top left, to bottom right, and from front page to back page.

For simplicity I've used X,Y,Z values of 5's as an example...

```
# X,Y,Z vector list

vector_list = [(5,5,5), (15,5,5),(20,5,5),(25,5,5), (5,10,5),(5,15,5)
(5,20,5), (5,25,5), (25,25,5), (15,25,5),(15, 5, 5), (10,5, 5), (20,20,5)]


# (Plots/reads like a book, from the top line (Y) - across left to right (X), - then in depth (Z).

# Sort order: 

# First via Highest Y values, vector_list[1]
# Second via Lowest X values, vector_list[0]
# Third via Lowest Z values, vector)list[2]

# Desired ouput (5, 25, 5), (15, 25, 5), (25, 25, 5),(5, 20, 5), (20, 20, 5)
# (5, 15, 5), (5, 10, 5) etc...
```

I can get the sorting to work via Y values, or via the total values, using

```
sorted(a, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

But can't follow up with sorting the X or Z without losing my sorted Y values.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
sorted(a, key=lambda tup: (-tup[1],tup[0],tup[2]))
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please consider marking it as Correct :)

Comment: I hope he rewards you properly for doing his homework :P

Comment: I get the feeling that's not happening any time soon

Comment: Not homework... My job! ;p I'm currently in a bar drinking a beer... Of course I will mark as correct + reward you guys ...When I've sobered up ;)

Comment: Hahah I never stopped believing